# Creating another thread in order to keep track of the application data

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm looking to create another thread in order to keep track of the game time in terms of seconds. The thread here is at 10ms in order for the animation to move smoothly but because the game time isn't running at 10ms, I would obviously need to keep track of it somehow but not sure how to do this in this case.

I have the following:

```
public class Test extends JPanel {

    public int time;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Collision Tester");
            Test game = new Test();

            frame.add(game);
            frame.setSize(500, 500);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            while (true) {
                game.repaint();
                //game.time++;  should not be here
                game.red();
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }   
    }
}
```

Comment: its waiting 10 millis + how long it takes for game.repaint() and game.red() so heres the problem. you would need to measure the time it takes for all of those and work from there

Comment: you should use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)` to start any activity of your GUI.

Comment: You need to measure time (such as using System.nanoTime()) as well as requesting a sleep. This is for 2 reasons, 1 as Neil says; you other methods take some time but also because; just because you ask for 10ms doesn't mean you'll get 10ms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need another thread. Instead, use `System.nanoTime()`

```
long timeBefore = System.nanoTime();
// Some code here
long timePassed = System.nanoTime() - timeBefore;
```

The `timePassed` variable will contain the number of *nanoseconds* elapsed. Use `TimeUnit` constants to convert to other units if needed.

Comment: These seems simple enough, but I'm not entirely sure how to implement this though.

Comment: It actually depends on what time do you want to keep track of. Frame time? Game time?

Comment: Right now, I'm using what's here as means of how smoothly I want an object to move in my animation. The number of pixels "moved" depends on the thread I currently have. However, what's happening is that some of the physics portion that require "time" are currently based on this thread. So I just basically need the time elapsed since the program started.

Comment: Then set the `timeBefore` at the start of the game, then calculate the time elapsed whn you need it. Don't forget this value is expressed in *nanoseconds*.

Answer (score 1):

```
class gameTimer extends Thread {
    int gameTime;  // time in miliseconds
   // This is the entry point for the second thread.
   void start()
   {
       gameTime=0;
       this.start(); //starts the thread by runing the run function.
   }
   }
   public void run() {
      while(1==1){
        try{
            gameTime++;
            thread.sleep(1); // sleeps for 1 milisecond
        }
        catch(exception e){}
      }
}
```

Now when you want to start the timer, just create a new instance and call the start method. 
Read this for further understanding of multi threading http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters you haven't made a new thread so the loop is going to be running as your main code not along-side it, meaning it will stop other processes from functioning properly here is what I would do:

```
public class Test extends JPanel implements Runnable{

    @Override //This will run as a new thread
    public void run(){
        long beforeTime;
        while(true){
            game.repaint();
            game.red(); //Im not sure what this exactly does  :P
            try{
                Thread.sleep(10); //Should always put in try catch as this can throw exceptions
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeInMillis() - beforeTime);
            beforeTime = System.currentTimeInMillis();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Collision Tester");
            Test game = new Test();
            Thread counter = new Thread(game);

            frame.add(game);
            frame.setSize(500, 500);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

            counter.start() // Starts the thread

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a variable to hold the start time. However, calling `Thread.sleep` on the main thread like you are doing is not going to make for a happy experience in Swing. You'd be better off using a timer:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Collision Tester");
    Test game = new Test();

    frame.add(game);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            game.repaint();
            game.time = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            game.red();
        }  
        });  
    }
    timer.start();
}
```

See [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more information.